# getopt optional parameters without the use of the format --name=value

Tags: bash, getopt

I have getopt from util-linux 2.38 on my system:

```
[davide@68YM9C3 tmp]$ getopt -V
getopt from util-linux 2.38
[davide@68YM9C3 tmp]$
```

I would like to have an optional parameter to a long option but I would like to input its value (when I intend to input it) without the use of the format

```
--option=value
```

opting for the format supported for the mandatory parameters

```
--option value
```

Example:

```
[davide@68YM9C3 ~]$ getopt -a -o abc: --long option:: -- -a -b -c a -option value
-a -b -c 'a' --option '' -- 'value'
```

You see here the value went into the non-option arguments after `--`
and `--option` took an empty value.
The intended response should have been much like when using `=`
but I would rather not be forced to use it

```
[davide@68YM9C3 ~]$ getopt -a -o abc: --long option:: -- -a -b -c a -option=value
-a -b -c 'a' --option 'value' --
```

Does anyone know if it can be done  by using getopt?
I don't particularly want to write a complicated `case` to properly distinguish optional parameters and options themselves.

Comment: If you end up writing a `case` statement you might as well give up the Getopt dependency entirely and write your option parsing from scratch.

Comment: Per [getopt(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html), `If the option has an optional argument, it must be written directly after the long option name, separated by '=', if present`. The problem for `getopt` is, if it tried to support an optional argument in the format you desire, it would be impossible to distinguish between an option followed by its optional argument and an option followed by a non-argument parameter. The use of `=` is necessary to eliminate this ambiguity.

Comment: I ended abandoning getopt and writing my own option parser altogether.

tjm3772 : what you say is only true if you want to pass an optional argument that begins with a "-", maybe getopt allows that but in my logic it would be silly to want to do that, and in making this assumption it made the case for handling the option parser much simpler than i expected.